# Trying to remove extra "-1" from image src's in a string using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

I've a big string with a ton of html in it and I'm trying to remove some extra `-1` from the image urls which wordpress is adding for no obvious reason.

`$content = '<img src="abc-1.jpg"> Blah blah <img src="def-1-1.jpg> etc';`

I'm using:

`$content = preg_replace('/-1/','',$content);`

So `abc-1.jpg` becomes `abc.jpg` That's working fine.

However `def-1-1.jpg` becomes `def.jpg` which is wrong. I need it to become `def-1.jpg`

I can't figure out how to sort this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
$content = preg_replace('/-1(?!-1)/','',$content);
```

Comment: I could marry you.